# Trying to use external node library with Dojo

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, js-xlsx

I'm using dojo for client-side development.  The project as a whole is built on Node, but for the front-end I am incorporating the use of Dojo. I'm relatively new to using dojo but I've managed so far to create my own custom widgets and display them on the html page with relatively few issues.  Now I'm trying to incorporate the use of an external Node.js library {**SheetJS**} in a dojo widget.  I've tried everything I could think of to get it to work, but it seems like each different thing I try I some different error than the previous attempt.

My file structure is something of the following:

```
My Project
   Public
      Dojo
         Dojo
         Dijit
         Dstore
         Templates
```

I've tried the following:

1. Adding the full xlsx folder downloaded from GitHub under the `public/dojo` folder.  Then I tried to do the following:

```
define([
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "xlsx/xlsx"
],
function (declare, xlsx) {
    // ... declare and other things ...
    /* Generate Workbook */
    console.log(xlsx); // prints: not-a-module
    var wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    var ws = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(tempArr);
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "SheetJS");

    /* Trigger Download with `writeFile` */
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, "SheetJS.csv", {compression:true});
});
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'book_new' of undefined

2. Using the script tag taken from the GitHub README: `<script lang="javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>`

```
define([
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"
],
function (declare) {
    // ... declare and other things ...
    /* Generate Workbook */
    console.log(XLSX); // prints: {}
    var xlsx = XLSX;
    var wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    var ws = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(tempArr);
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "SheetJS");

    /* Trigger Download with `writeFile` */
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, "SheetJS.csv", {compression:true});
});
```

The error here is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'book_new' of undefined

3. `cd`ing into `public/dojo/dojo/` and doing an `npm install xlsx` then trying to do the following:

```
define([
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "dojo/node!xlsx"
],
function (declare, xlsx) {
    // ... declare and other things ...
    /* Generate Workbook */
    console.log(xlsx);
    var wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    var ws = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(tempArr);
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "SheetJS");

    /* Trigger Download with `writeFile` */
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, "SheetJS.csv", {compression:true});
});
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find the Node.js require

I wonder if the problem has something to do with the XLSX library and when it tries to find `XLSX.utils` it can't find the util that I want to use?

All ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance for any help or ideas that come my way.

Answer (score 0):

When you `npm install xlsx` the xlsx library will be installed inside `node_modules` folder of your project.

I'm not completely sure about your current project structure but the project should be found relatively from your Dojo widget.

For example:

```
define([
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "./../node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js"  //change it until it will be found
],
function (declare, xlsx) {
    console.log(xlsx);
    var wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    var ws = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(tempArr);
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "SheetJS");

    /* Trigger Download with `writeFile` */
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, "SheetJS.csv", {compression:true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been in your situation for a few days now, and Ferry's solution does not work. It seems that it is something to do with SheetJS, and the solved tickets there regarding AMD/DOJO does not work either.

Your best bet would be to use ExcelJS. In this case, this is what works for me:

```html
define([
'dojo/_base/declare', 
'jimu/BaseWidget',
'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exceljs/4.3.0/exceljs.min.js'
], function (declare, BaseWidget, ExcelJS) {
    return declare([BaseWidget], {
        baseClass: 'x-x-x',
        name: "x",
        className: 'xxx.xxxxxx.xxxx',

        postCreate: function () {

        },

        startup: function () {
            const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
            console.log(workbook);
        },
    });
});
```